# Create a LWC lookup field without creating new record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup

I have a custom lwc that isn't directly linked to an object instance.

On this lwc, I would like to use the lwc lookup input to lookup a related object and get its id.

I'm struggling to do this, as it seems that lookup fields require either a new object or an existing object instance to work.

Is there anyway to use this lookup field without modifying or creating new object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've observed, the built-in component needs a record to work with. However, there are open source versions (try searching for ["lwc lookup field github"](https://www.google.com/search?q=lwc+lookup+field+github&oq=lwc+lookup+field+github)) that you could modify to work without a record.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out an alternative lookup component (more lightweight) [here](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2019/06/simple-lightning-datatable-using.html). It's not exactly what you are looking for but you can iterate and extend this component for a related object.